# Android: TextView visibility changes

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, visibility

I have started with android programming and I am trying to do:

1. Let the user enter their login credential.
2. If the user login credential is valid let them login.
3. If login credential is invalid then give them an error message saying that the user name or password entered is invalid.

For the last part, the problem is that I have a `TextView` with default hidden visibility. I want to make it visible for a few seconds and make it disappear.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242955/how-to-display-a-textview-for-few-seconds-and-then-make-it-invisible) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194761/hide-textview-after-some-time-in-android) post have helped but they are essentially trying to do the opposite.

My code is given below:

```
 submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // Check the validity of the user name.
       if (valid) {
          // Let the user log in.
       } else {
          // Make TextView visible for a few seconds.
       }
    }
 });
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Do you know thread? Or just Why don't you use toast

Comment: @Sarz toast? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: As Sarz said Toast would be fine if you dont need user's confirmation. If you need a confirmation from the user you can use Alert dialog.

Comment: ok in else set textview  visibility visible . and in username types make textview gone

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava now, if your problem is solved you can accept any of the answer as you like to close this question.

Comment: Sorry, was AFK. Just came back. I'll go through the answers and do the needful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case first you need to show TextView then make it  `INVISIBLE` .

Use textView.postDelayed method as:

```
   if(valid){  //let the user login }
    else
    {
         // make TextView visible here
          textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
          //use postDelayed to hide TextView 
          textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
               textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              }
         }, 3000);
        //how to make the textview visible for a few seconds
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To show any information or error message you can use small pop-up message for some time. Following the code and image for toast.

```
//display in short period of time
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use toast.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

[Toasts in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with the help of timertask,as your textview is invisible first make it visible and then with the help of timertask make it invisible again

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
//check the validity of the user name
if(valid)
{
    //let the user login
}
else
{
 txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 Timer t = new Timer(false);
 t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
 @Override
  public void run() {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
}, 5000);
}
});
```

but i would suggest if you want user confirmation show error in alertdialog or a toast to show error would be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using handler.

```
 submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
    //check the validity of the user name
    if(valid)
    {
        //let the user login
    }
    else
    {
        //how to make the textview visible for a few seconds
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                        mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
            }, 1000/* 1sec delay */);
    }
});
```