# How do you hide TextViews in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194761/hide-textview-after-some-time-in-android) article some time ago, but I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to hide TextViews in Kotlin?

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
fun damagePopup( playerHitMonster:View , monsterHitPlayer:View ) {
    val playerDamageText = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(playerDam)
    binding.playerHitMonster.text = getString(R.string.playerHitDam, playerDamageText)
    playerHitMonster.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val monsterDamageText = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(monsterDam)
    binding.monsterHitPlayer.text = getString(R.string.monsterHitDam, monsterDamageText)
    monsterHitPlayer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

Comment: Wasn’t me, but probably because this is a trivial thing you could find in the class’s documentation.

Comment: are `monsterHitPlayer` and `playerHitMonster` bound elsewhere because you are accessing them two different ways.  `binding.monsterHitPlayer.text`  and   `monsterHitPlayer.visibility`  try `binding.monsterHitPlayer.visibility = View.VISIBLE`

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE // default can see it
textView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE //keeps size just cant see it. 
textView.visibility = View.GONE // size goes to 0 0 and cant see it.
```

Comment: Hm... `visibility` is an unresolved reference. Is there a library/package I need to import?

Comment: I added parameters for the views `fun showText (myView: View)`, but when I call the function, it says I need to add parameters. What's going on?

Comment: post what you have written